# Single template in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to use Rails with [Angularjs](http://angularjs.org/). Angular will do all the client side work while Rails controllers suppose to handle requests to list and modify information (in Database).

I have a simple template in views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SomeApp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "vendors", :media => "all" %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper" ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="SomeApprCtrl">
      <%= render 'header' %>
      <div ng-view=""></div>
      <%= render 'footer' %>
    </div>
  </div><!-- End on wrapper -->
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
</body>
</html>
```

This template does everything i need to start Angular. But i need to put something in Rails routes. I need to define controller and action. Say something like this:

```
root :to => 'main#index'
```

And this mean that I need to define controller Main with only one empty method `index` and totally empty template file in views/main/index.html. How can i avoid appearance of this empty useless files?

I was thinking of using `root :to => 'application#index'` and define empty `index` method in ApplicationController but since this controller is basic for inheritance to all other controllers i don't want them to have any crap. Also this approach does not solves problem with empty `index.html` template

Answer (score 0):

While it is empty the controller is actually handling a lot by convention.  It automatically displays the `index.html.erb` view, and since the layout hasn't been specified it wraps it in the `application.html.erb` layout.

So while the file may be sparse there's a lot going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Still `index.html.erb` will be empty for no reason. Are there any way to avoid it's usage?

Comment: So why are you using Rails in the first place?  Why not a Rack app, which doesn't have the overhead that Rails entails.

Comment: Because I'm very new to Rails and have no idea could it be replaced with Rake or not. In most cases only thing i need from backend is to get data from DB and respond with JSON.

Comment: There's a new Railscast video that is similar to what you're trying.  Unfortunately it's in the paid tier: http://railscasts.com/episodes/408-ember-part-1  but Ryan has the source code on Github @ https://github.com/railscasts/408-ember-part-1.  Reading through it I bet will be a big help.  It also has a single page design.